# Java/Wicket: Compile Basic Hello World with Resources

Tags: java, maven, wicket

I am following this example of a Hello World Wicket application

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-wicket/

In particular I placed `HelloWorld.html` in my source directory next to `HelloWorld.java`.

My file structure looks like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── example
│   │   │           └── wicket
│   │   │               ├── HelloWorld.html
│   │   │               ├── HelloWorld.java
│   │   │               └── HelloWorldApplication.java
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       └── WEB-INF
│   │           └── web.xml
│   └── test
│       └── java
└── wicketTest.iml
```

However when I compile this to a war file, and load in Jetty, i recieve this error, in the browser:

```
Unexpected RuntimeException

Last cause: Can not determine Markup. Component is not yet connected to a parent. [Page class = com.example.wicket.HelloWorld, id = 4, render count = 1]

Stacktrace

Root cause:

org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException: Can not determine Markup. Component is not yet connected to a parent. [Page class = com.example.wicket.HelloWorld, id = 4, render count = 1]
     at org.apache.wicket.Component.getMarkup(Component.java:737)
     at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2344)
     at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2307)
     at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1010)
```

When I look in the war file I notice that the html file is missing:

```
$ tar tvf target/wicketTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
drwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 Aug 22 14:50 META-INF/
-rwxrwxrwx  0 0      0         128 Aug 22 14:50 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
drwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 Aug 22 14:50 WEB-INF/
drwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 Aug 22 14:50 WEB-INF/classes/
drwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 Aug 22 14:50 WEB-INF/classes/com/
drwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 Aug 22 14:50 WEB-INF/classes/com/example/
drwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 Aug 22 14:50 WEB-INF/classes/com/example/wicket/
drwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 Aug 22 14:50 WEB-INF/lib/
-rwxrwxrwx  0 0      0         608 Aug 22 14:50 WEB-INF/classes/com/example/wicket/HelloWorld.class
-rwxrwxrwx  0 0      0         551 Aug 22 14:50 WEB-INF/classes/com/example/wicket/HelloWorldApplication.class
-rwxrwxrwx  0 0      0       25962 Aug 21 16:07 WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
-rwxrwxrwx  0 0      0     2126440 Aug 21 16:07 WEB-INF/lib/wicket-core-6.10.0.jar
-rwxrwxrwx  0 0      0       86671 Aug 21 16:07 WEB-INF/lib/wicket-request-6.10.0.jar
-rwxrwxrwx  0 0      0      415858 Aug 21 16:07 WEB-INF/lib/wicket-util-6.10.0.jar
-rwxrwxrwx  0 0      0         690 Aug 22 13:22 WEB-INF/web.xml
drwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 Aug 22 14:50 META-INF/maven/
drwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 Aug 22 14:50 META-INF/maven/wicketTest/
drwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 Aug 22 14:50 META-INF/maven/wicketTest/wicketTest/
-rwxrwxrwx  0 0      0         675 Aug 22 08:52 META-INF/maven/wicketTest/wicketTest/pom.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  0 0      0         112 Aug 22 14:50 META-INF/maven/wicketTest/wicketTest/pom.properties
```

How do I specify in my POM file to include the html file?

My POM right now is minimal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>wicketTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicketTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Why not just use the quickstart generator available from http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html? You are then one paste away from a working application. At least you can diff the pom.xml from the quick start with the pom.xml you crafted.

Comment: Thanks, that got me the solution as you mentioned.  Posted below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution, if you want your HTML in the wicket best practice place (with your classes) is to add this to the build section of your pom.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: good explanation. Why did you deactivate filtering for `src/main/resources` ?

Answer (score 1):

If using Maven, see David Williams' answer. If using Gradle, see this answer.

Include the following in your `build.gradle` file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs += ['src/main/java']
            includes = ["**"]
            // or specifically: includes = ["**/*.html"]
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures that the HTML files will be added to the WAR file.

Answer (score 0):

You should put you `HelloWorld.html` file into `src/main/webapp` folder. This way it will be included in the war file

Comment: No doubt this would work but the answer from David Williams is better since it follows Wicket best practises.

Comment: Which best practices to follow is always a trade off. Mine answer is considering maven best practices.

Comment: And not just into src/main/webapp directory, but in src/main/webapp/com/example/wicket.

Comment: Embedding the HTML inside your war is good for most applications but one of the awesome things about Wicket is that you can control the layout and even the component composition (see createComponent method) at runtime by simply changing you HTML. To do that you want to store your markup outside of your war file to avoid having to rebuild and redeploy your app each time you make a markup change. We've built a large CMS, http://pagebloom.com, with Wicket using this method.